# .NETLink Graphics producing PNG instead of EMF

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The C# code below should produce an EMF, but viewing the output (in Vim) shows it to be a PNG.  Perhaps someone on S.O. knows a good work-around or solution.

```
MathKernel k = new MathKernel();
k.CaptureGraphics = true;
k.GraphicsFormat = "Metafile";
k.Compute("Show[Graphics[{Thick, Blue, Circle[{#, 0}] & /@ Range[4], Black, Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {5, 0}}]}]]");
k.Graphics[0].Save("C:\\Temp\\file.emf", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf);
```

So far I'm considering wrapping Show[Graphics...] in ExportString[... , "EMF"] and collecting the result using the MathKernel Result property.

**Addendum**

The MathKernel.Graphics property[1] is apparently a .Net Graphics method which only handles image files such as bitmaps, not vector graphic based enhanced metafiles.

1. http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/NETLink/ref/net/Wolfram.NETLink.MathKernel.Graphics.html

Enhanced metafiles can be transferred through .NETLink one at a time though, in the following manner:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Wolfram.NETLink;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        MathKernel k = new MathKernel();
        k.Compute("ExportString[Graphics[{Disk[]}], {\"Base64\", \"EMF\"}]");
        byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(k.Result.ToString());
        // The transferred EMF can be used or simply written out to file.
        File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\file.emf", decodedBytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you launched a non-interactive FrontEnd process from the MathKernel and configured the latted to use the former as the `$FrontEnd`? Probably EMF files are produced by the FrontEnd and cannot be created without it. Note also that *Mathematica* can export EMF files only under Windows.

Comment: @ Alexey - Thanks. It may well be that EMFs are only produced in the FrontEnd. MathKernel.GraphicsFormat lists "Metafile" as an output format though. Will see.  http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/NETLink/ref/net/Wolfram.NETLink.MathKernel.GraphicsFormat.html

Comment: On that page the PNG format you get is not listed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working solution:

```
using System;
using Wolfram.NETLink;

public class Example {

 public static void Main(String[] args) {

  MathKernel k = new MathKernel();
  k.Compute("Export[\"c:/users/arnoudb/out.emf\", Graphics[{Disk[]}], \"EMF\"]");
  }

}
```

I am not sure why you consider this part:

```
k.Graphics[0].Save("C:\\Temp\\file.emf", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf);
```

a Mathematica bug, since k.Graphics[0] is a pure C# System.Drawing.Image class. Perhaps you can clarify this part a bit?

Comment: @ Arnoud, Thanks again. It is surprising that the .Net Graphics method/class doesn't handle EMFs, which would be useful for accumulated graphics. I have edited my original post, and added a method for transferring single EMFs without having to write them out to disk.