# Wolfram .NET connector EvaluateToImage gives an animation

Tags: c#, wolfram-mathematica

I have an `Expr` object in C#, which represents `Wolfram Mathematica`'s type - it can hold a number, a mathematical expression, a sound, an image or others.

I had been using the tutorial included with my `Wolfram Mathemtica` edition for calling `Mathematica` via .NET, and I want to create an Image from my output. For example, to plot a function or nicely draw an expression.

I have this code:

```
public System.Drawing.Image ToImage(int width = 300, int height = 300)
{
    return link.EvaluateToImage(this.e, width, height);
}
```

Where `link` is my `IKernelLink`, and `this.e` is my `Expr`.
Afterwards, I use `image.Save(@"C:\file.png")`
The problem is that when I open a form and do `form.pictureBox.Image = LoadImage(@"C:\file.png")`, or I open the the image with the appropriate program, it gives me an animation of three frames. I will upload it here:

[image]

Additionally, it does not give me the whole output, which is `{{x -> -(-3)^(1/3)}, {x -> 
3^(1/3)}, {x -> (-1)^(2/3)*3^(1/3)}}` (generated with `EvaluateToInputForm`)
Obviously, this behavior is wrong and can anybody help me with it?

note: it makes a single frame file when the `Expr` is a graphic object, i.e the evaluation of a `Plot` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use a Graphics array to send a collection of images from Mathematica to .NET, ie:

[.NET/Link MathKernel.Graphics Property](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/NETLink/ref/net/Wolfram.NETLink.MathKernel.Graphics.html)

There is an example of the use of this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542828/netlink-graphics-producing-png-instead-of-emf).